# Bluetooth and window manager in 18.04

Tags: bluetooth

I cannot get the bluetooth to work when loggin into a different widow manager than Gnome. The gnome-control-center, which I launch like this:

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME; gnome-control-center
```

tells me that there is no bluetooth and thus I cannot even click on the bluetooth ON/OFF button.

The bluetooth works okay in the Gnome desktop environment and this only happens when using a different window manager (Awesome WM or I3WM for example). I assume I miss some service which is started when loggin into Gnome?

Can anybody help please?

Regards,
Alfredo

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04.2 and i3

Comment: Any news on that? I experienced the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing blueman, a Bluetooth manager

`sudo apt install blueman`

after installing run `blueman` from terminal. This will also add Bluetooth icon on system tray(It did on qtile).

Now you can pair or connect by pressing on the Bluetooth icon in system tray.